# How do I start an AlarmActivity from the background when app is not running?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, alarm, foreground-service

I'm working on the alarm component of an app; I schedule an alarm using `AlarmManager`, and handle the trigger using a static `BroadcastReceiver`, which runs a service that is supposed to start the `AlarmActivity` by waking device and displaying animated screen notifying the user of an alarm (besides a notification). The hassle is in starting `AlarmActivity` from `AlarmService`; I keep getting the error

```
E/.thengnet.medi: [qarth_debug:]  get PatchStore::createDisableExceptionQarthFile method fail.
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.blogspot.thengnet.medic, PID: 12588
android.app.RemoteServiceException: Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground(): ServiceRecord{9c39969 u0 com.blogspot.thengnet.medic/.services.AlarmService}
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2126)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:112)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
```

which crashes the app, and I lose all scheduled alarms, (until I reopen the app, whence it *probably* **repeats the cycle**), after *notifying the notification it builds*.

I need to schedule alarms that can open `AlarmActivity` whether app is open or closed -- in bg/fg -- actively used, or after a reboot.

Here's my code (**buggy part at the end**):

[AlarmBroadcastReceiver](https://github.com/Detective-Khalifah/MEDIC_--_Localised_Personal_Health_Tracker_Extended/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/blogspot/thengnet/medic/receivers/AlarmBroadcastReceiver.java)

```
    private void startAlarmService(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent alarmIntentService = new Intent(context, AlarmService.class);
//        alarmIntentService.putExtra(label, intent.getStringExtra(label));
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            context.startForegroundService(alarmIntentService);
        } else {
            context.startService(alarmIntentService);
        }
    }
```

[AlarmService](https://github.com/Detective-Khalifah/MEDIC_--_Localised_Personal_Health_Tracker_Extended/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/blogspot/thengnet/medic/services/AlarmService.java)

```
public AlarmService () {
        super(AlarmService.class.getName());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent (@Nullable Intent intent) {
        NotificationUtil.notifyUserToTakeMeds(getApplicationContext());
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmActivity.class);
        intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent1);
    }

}
```

Comment: This is not how you should be handling alarm clock type of behaviors. Did you [read the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/time-sensitive)?

Comment: Removed `android-studio` tag as that tag is for problems/questions related to the Android Studio product. Your question is a generic Android question and has nothing to do with Android Studio.

Comment: I definitely did not read that part, @ianhanniballake; first time using the `Service` class.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this crash is right in the exception text:

```
android.app.RemoteServiceException: Context.startForegroundService() did not then call
Service.startForeground(): ServiceRecord{9c39969 u0
com.blogspot.thengnet.medic/.services.AlarmService}
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2126)
```

Your `Service` must declare itself as a **foreground service** by calling `startForeground()` in the `handleMessage()` method. You need to add that.

Comment: `handleMessage()` is from the `Handler` [class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler#handleMessage(android.os.Message); should I be _extending_ it instead of `IntentService`?

Comment: I tried `new Handler() {}`, where I override `handleMessage()`; `startForeground()` requires reference to the `Notification` object, which I built in a separate utility [class](https://github.com/Detective-Khalifah/MEDIC_--_Localised_Personal_Health_Tracker_Extended/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/blogspot/thengnet/medic/utilities/NotificationUtil.java)... I'm stumped

Comment: Sorry, I should have written `onHandleIntent()`, not `handleMessage()`. You just need to call `startForeground()` inside `onHandleIntent()`.

Comment: It works; `Activity` gets started without hassle (seemingly); only, the notification isn't displayed. I copied code from the `NotificationUtils` class to build the notification, and call `startForeground(id, notificationBuilder.build())` proceeded by `Intent intent1 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmActivity.class); intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); startActivity(intent1);`

Comment: I would have to call `notify(id, notificationBuilder.build(());` on a `NotificationManager` object; what's the essence of passing a `Notification` to `startForeground()`, if I would have to call `notificationManager.notify(id, notificationBuilder.build());` ?

I haven't grasped it, or there's some redundant call(s) to be made.

Comment: Not sure I understand your comment. You must provide a `Notification` when you call `startForeground()`. Normally this is shown in the notification bar as long as your foreground `Service` is running. However, you mentioned that your `Service` is an `IntentService`, which is only alive until the `onHandleIntent()` method completes, then it terminates itself. So your architecture doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: Sloppy architecture, I guess.
The notification is not being displayed in the notification bar.

Comment: If you are using `IntentService`, then the Notification probably won't get displayed since the `Service` is stopped immediately after you post it.

Comment: I'll read up some documentation and catch up later; extending `Service` does it, but I don't think I'm doing it right -- definitely not the ideal way to set up an Alarm `Activity` & relevant `Notification` (`NotificationGroup` aside).

Comment: Well, the thing is, you aren't really supposed to launch an `Activity` on your own. This may disturb the user in the middle of whatever they are doing. This is why Android makes this so difficult. If you want to tell the user something, you should simply post a Notification. The user can then look at the Notification when they decide to, and open it or dismiss it as needed.

Comment: Hope they fix that soon.
I'm able to display `Notification` and/or  `AlarmActivity`.
Tried lowering the notification importance & importance from HIGH/MAX, to see if that would make it possible to disable the notification's persistence on notification panel -- I CAN'T SWIPE IT OFF; I tried DEFAULT, LOW, then MIN, but none did the job -- notification still can't be swiped off, and to add salt to injury, AlarmActivity isn't displayed anymore.

**Not a slow reader, have had other commitments that got me busily engaged, I haven't turned on my PC in a week.